# Morphism between integral domain and field is injective?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, integral-domain, morphism

I just read in my linear algebra's notes the following statement :
Let A be an integral domain and K a field. Any nonzero ring morphism $\phi : A \to K$ is injective.

I think this statement is false by considering the morphism $$\phi : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z /2 \mathbb Z$$
$$n \to [n]$$
This is a morphism between an integral domain and a field but clearly not injective.

So is the statement wrong ? I am quite sure of the counterexample but each time I disagreed with my teacher's notes, I was wrong.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3432696/every-ring-morphism-from-an-integral-domain-to-a-field-is-injective)

Comment: You are definitely correct.  Maybe it was supposed to go the other way, $K \to A$? In that case, the only ideal in a field is the zero ideal, so the the only possibility for the kernel is zero.

Comment: You're right. More generally, consider a (nonzero) maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ in an integral domain $A$. The morphism $A\longrightarrow A/\mathfrak m$ is surjective, and its kernel is the maximal ideal.

Comment: Thanks for your answers ! @Nick in fact we already demonstrated this statement before this "false" one, maybe the teacher wanted to say " $\exists$ an injective morphism $A \to K$ "

Comment: There need not exist any injective morphisms $A \to K$! For example, there are no injective functions $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct. Here are two possibilities for what the statement should have been:

1. Any morphism from $K \to A$ is injective (because the kernel is an ideal of $K$ and the only ideals are $(0)$ and $(1) = K$). It doesn't matter so much that $A$ is an integral domain here other than to know that $A \neq 0$. If $A$ were $0$ then $K \to 0$ is non-injective.
2. The map $A \to \operatorname{Frac}(A)$ is injective.